# how to display a date which is stored in database as string as a text field in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Actually my database consists a date which is given as "VARCHAR(50)".So in jasper report it is displaying as "java.lang.String" and in preview its getting very well.But when i change my preview to "msword preview" the date field is not getting as shown in below.[image]

report.jrxml

```
<field name="Followup_Date" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="690" y="0" width="75" height="31" uuid="3a9c7a9b-77bf-4b74-a119-4076fbbe9907">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="false"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Followup_Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Comment: That's really strange... first remove al the property settings you have in reportElement (don't understand why they are there, they should be under the jasperReport tag if you need them) then check that height="31" is within the size of your detail band... if still problem we will need whole jrxml to see if other elements are causing your problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Date field is aligned with other field,so its not getting displayed.Now i fixed that.Thanks once again

Comment: What happend to the answer?... it seemed correct...

Comment: @PetterFriberg yeah actually the date field is overlapped with some other text field.I fixed that and now it is working fine

Comment: The original answer was phrased as a question and so deleted. I've fixed this now!

Comment: @jtsnr, ok, great, sorry I always feel the need to close the questions and since your answer was correct... I was asking myself where did it go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The borders of the date field overlap another field. This causes problems when reports are exported.